# I can't do methods made work in Laravel API

Tags: laravel, laravel-api

I am using Laravel to create records using `API`in `api.php` than using the form, but I am having difficulties with the methods, for example the `store()` method is not inserting the record I want in `Postman` when I enter the URL `http://localhost:8000/api/store` of type `POST`. My database is enable and Apache Laravel is also enable.

The error is this:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/api/store: {
  "Error": "connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000",
  "Request Headers": {
    "description": "A+",
    "user-agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.35.0",
    "accept": "*/*",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "7adc02d9-f53e-4aa0-8552-04fe9fdff882",
    "host": "localhost:8000",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "connection": "keep-alive"
  },
  "Request Body": {}
}
```

- `api.php`

```
    <?php
    
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    use App\Http\Controllers\TypeBloodController;
    
    Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });
    
    Route::apiResources([
        'blood_type' => TypeBloodController::class,
    ]);
```

- `TypeBloodController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\TypeBloodRequest;
use App\Models\TypeBloodModel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TypeBloodController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $type_blood = TypeBloodModel::all();
        return response()->json($type_blood, 200);
    }

    public function store(TypeBloodRequest $request)
    {
        $validations = $request->validated();

        $treated_datas = [
            'description' => trim((string) $validations['description']),
        ];

        $type_blood = TypeBloodModel::create($treated_datas);

        return response()->json($tipo_hunter, 201);
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $type_blood = TypeBloodModel::find($id);

        if (!$type_blood) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Resource not found'], 404);
        }

        return response()->json($type_blood, 200);
    }

    public function update(TypeBloodRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $validations = $request->validated();

        $treated_datas = [
            'description' => trim((string) $validations['description']),
        ];

        $type_blood = TypeBloodModelModel::where('id', $id)->update($treated_datas);

        return response()->json($tipo_hunter, 201);
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        TypeBloodModel::where('id', $id)->delete();
        return response()->json(null, 204);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you navigate to http://localhost:8000/, what happens? Connection refused is likely not Laravel at all, and Apache probably isn't running on port 8000.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that your Laravel development server is running on port 8000 or not

I check on my side and generate same error like this
[image]

I think your laravel server is not running on port 8000

Comment: I already solved my question.

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: The route and urls.

Answer (score -2):

You understand that `store` is just the name of the function that handles POST on the endpoint `/api/blood_type` right? You typically do not append the names of handler/controller functions to the end of the route.

try a POST to `/api/blood_type`

Comment: "Connection refused" is something before it even hits Laravel.

Comment: Still a major issue he is going to run into if he is trying to call the functions by name on the end of a URI